# Local repository was randomly removed and project lost connection to repository

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a clone of a repository in my computer. Until today everything worked fine, i used tortoisegit to create branches to pull and push and resolve merge conflicts. Today what happened, was that i was working on a task. I completed it and i wanted to commit it to the repository, but in tortoisegit menu there were no options to do so only: clone repository here, create new repository here and settings. It seems it got disconnected from the remote repository and local repository. So i though i just clone the project into a new location and see if i can access the local branches from there and maybe copy paste my code to the new folder and then commit and push. But i cannot.

What can cause a directory from completely disconnecting from remote and local repo? And also possibly removing the local repository? Is there a way to restore everything?

Comment: please see in this [reference](https://www.toolsqa.com/git/local-repository-remote-repository/) HTH.

Comment: hmm.. this expecs the remote to be empty and local to exist. But remote is not empty and it seems local repo is also removed

Comment: description of the questions is not that much clear. Please explain it with appropriate details which would help others to help you .like what kind of messages/errors you are observing and folder structur where you are trying it out .

Comment: Have you deleted the `.git` folder?

Comment: @MrTux no .git folder is gone. Its not even in recycling bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out .git folder was somehow deleted. It was not even in recycling bin. I had to clone the project again and then copy pasted the changed code there. That fixed it.

Sill a mystery why .git folder disappeared.